# Losing data in a GroupJoin C# and LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to join data from two tables, but I am getting weird behavior and losing information that is needed. I'm having to use a GroupJoin due to the fact some items may not exist on one table as they do the other.

```
    var joinedItems = context.TableOne.GroupJoin(context.TableTwo,
                                    i => i.ItemID,
                                    j => j.ItemID,
                                    (i, j) => new
                                    {
                                        i,
                                        j,
                                    })
                                    .Select(x => new
                                    {
                                        ID = x.i.ItemID,
                                        MonthID = x.i.MonthID,
                                        Rating = x.i.Rating,
                                        ItemStatus = x.i.Status,
                                        Tier = x.j.FirstOrDefault().Tier,
                                        TierStatus = x.j.FirstOrDefault().Status,
                                    }).Where(x => prevMonths.Contains(x.MonthID ?? 0)).ToArray();
```

prevMonths is just an array that contains the IDs of the months I am wanting of the items (in this case, the first 3 months).
For reference, one of the items causing issues where I am losing information:

```
Table One
----------
ItemID     MonthID    Rating     Status   . . .
96        5         12      Available
{ MonthID 2 - 4 are just straight up missing from the table }
96        1         9       Available

Table Two
---------
ItemID     MonthID     Tier      Status   . . .
96        5          5      Available
96        4        NULL        N/A
96        3        NULL        N/A
96        2        NULL        N/A
```

When it gets joined, the index for 96 is shown as

```
{ ID: 96, MonthID: 5, Rating: 12, ItemStatus: Available, Tier: , TierStatus: }
```

I am not sure why it is not joining the data from TableTwo to TableOne properly. My only assumption is that GroupJoin does some weird behavior when records aren't there so it just doesn't know how to link them together properly.

This issue extends through multiple items, this is just one example I am focused on.

Comment: So which output do you expect? The phrase "data loss" doesn't apply, because you're only querying, not saving data. I seems that you want to show data for a specified set of months, also when there's no data for that month, but if `prevMonths` dictates which month are to be shown you need a different approach. Another question: is the combination `ItemID/MonthID` unique in each table?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to perform left join via LINQ. The most correct approach would be to setup relations between the entities and use the navigation properties (i.e. something like `context.TableOne.Include(to => to.TableTwos)...`).

If you still need/want to perform left join via the LINQ you can use either query syntax:

```
from i in context.TableOne.Where(x => prevMonths.Contains(x.MonthID ?? 0))
join j in context.TableTwo on i.ItemID equals j.ItemID  into ps
from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {...} // use i and p
```

For method syntax you should try something like:

```
var joinedItems = context.TableOne
    .Where(x => prevMonths.Contains(x.MonthID ?? 0))
    .GroupJoin(context.TableTwo,
        i => i.ItemID,
        j => j.ItemID,
        (i, j) => new {i, js})
    .SelectMany(
        x => x.js.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (x, j) => new { i = x.i, j=j}) // actual select here
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: This does work, however, now I have a lot of repeated records of the same thing but some have null values. Like for example `{ ID: 96, MonthID: 5, Rating: 12, ItemStatus: Available, Tier: 5, TierStatus: Available }` is repeated 10+ times with a few of `{ ID: 96, MonthID: 5, Rating: 12, ItemStatus: Available, Tier: , TierStatus: }` sprinkled in with the missing data. Not to mention other records with more data available to them. I have now roughly 1300 elements stored in the array with most of them are repeated. Tried other things to slim it down, but it is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: @CodedRoses because it is a left join. Alternatively you can try changing your original query to use `DefaultIfEmpty` - like `x.j..DefaultIfEmpty().FirstOrDefault().Tier` but not sure if EF will be able to translate it.

Comment: Right, i tried using .Distinct() but it looks like it pulled values from other MonthIDs and just added them into items that do not correlate. The alternative you provided also did not work, it led to the same issue shown in my example.

Answer (score -3):

The behavior you're observing is due to how GroupJoin works. When you use GroupJoin, it will join the items from TableOne with the items from TableTwo based on the key you've specified (ItemID). If there are no matching items in TableTwo for a particular item in TableOne, the result will be an empty collection for that item.

In your case, for ItemID 96, you have two entries in TableOne for MonthID 5 and 1. However, in TableTwo, you have entries for MonthID 5, 4, 3, and 2. The GroupJoin will only join the items that have a matching ItemID in both tables. So, for ItemID 96 and MonthID 5, you get a match, but for MonthID 1, there's no corresponding entry in TableTwo, so the Tier and TierStatus values are null.

Try performing a *join* between the two tables based on ItemID and then filter the results based on MonthID. Here's how you can do it:

```
var joinedItems = context.TableOne
    .Join(context.TableTwo, i => i.ItemID, j => j.ItemID, (i, j) => new { i, j })
    .Where(x => x.i.MonthID == x.j.MonthID && prevMonths.Contains(x.i.MonthID))
    .Select(x => new
    {
        ID = x.i.ContractID,
        MonthID = x.i.MonthID,
        Rating = x.i.Rating,
        ItemStatus = x.i.Status,
        Tier = x.j.Tier,
        TierStatus = x.j.Status,
    })
    .ToArray();
```

This should be able to provide similar outcome where data from TableTwo is joined with TableOne based on both ItemID and MonthID.

***EDITED VERSION 2***

Based off of *u/CodedRoses* feedback, updated code:

```
var joinedItems = context.TableOne.GroupJoin(context.TableTwo,
                                    i => new { i.ItemID, i.MonthID },
                                    j => new { j.ItemID, j.MonthID },
                                    (i, j) => new
                                    {
                                        i,
                                        j = j.DefaultIfEmpty() // This ensures that you get a collection with a single null item if there's no match in TableTwo
                                    })
                                    .Where(x => prevMonths.Contains(x.i.MonthID))
                                    .Select(x => new
                                    {
                                        ID = x.i.ContractID,
                                        MonthID = x.i.MonthID,
                                        Rating = x.i.Rating,
                                        ItemStatus = x.i.Status,
                                        Tier = x.j.FirstOrDefault()?.Tier, // Use the null conditional operator to handle the case where the item is null
                                        TierStatus = x.j.FirstOrDefault()?.Status, // Same here
                                    })
                                    .ToArray();
```

By using `DefaultIfEmpty()`, you ensure that you get a collection with a single null item for each item from `TableOne` that has no matching item in `TableTwo`. This allows you to include all items from `TableOne` in the result. The null conditional operator (`?.`) is then used to handle the case where the item from `TableTwo` is null.

Regarding the issue with filtering by month before the `Select` statement, the problem is that the `Where` clause is applied after the `GroupJoin`, so it filters out items from `TableOne` that don't have a matching item in `TableTwo` for the specified months. By moving the `Where` clause before the `GroupJoin`, you ensure that you only join the items from `TableOne` that match the specified months.

Comment: The issue I have with using .Join() is that if a record doesn't exist in Table Two but it does in Table One then it leaves it completely out of the array by not being selected. So I am ultimately forced to use a GroupJoin. I do understand that it will only join where the ItemID and MonthID matches which is perfect, but for some reason it leaves off some values like shown in my example. It is fine if it doesn't have all the months, I just feel like that could be the cause of why for the item of MonthID = 5, it's tier doesn't have a value when joined together although it does in the table.

Comment: Oh, and when I do the filtering by the month before the select statement, it selects nothing and I'm left with an array of 0 elements which is also weird. But I'm assuming that's just some behavior when using GroupJoin.

Comment: The behavior you're observing is indeed due to the nature of GroupJoin. When you use GroupJoin, the result for each item from TableOne is a collection of matching items from TableTwo. If there are no matching items in TableTwo, this collection will be empty.

Given what you said you want to include all items from TableOne even if there's no matching item in TableTwo. To achieve this, you can still use GroupJoin, but you need to handle the case where the collection of matching items from TableTwo is empty. I can modify my earlier response to address this too.

Comment: When trying to lambda i, j into those object types `{ i.ItemID, i.MonthID },` it gives me an error of `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type`. So I just did `i => i.ItemID`, same thing with j and still resulting in the same issue.

Comment: I feel like I should mention some items work perfectly fine and grab all the values and the correct corresponding ones, but others result in the post example issue.

Comment: @jimmykurian You didn't notice that OP doesn't even use `GroupJoin`. What you posted the first time missed the mark completely and almost repeated there own code, clearly demonstrating that it was a generated answer that you didn't understand yourself.

Comment: @GertArnold My initial response aimed to explain the behavior of `GroupJoin` and why the user might be experiencing the issues they described. The goal was to provide a deeper understanding of how `GroupJoin` works in LINQ and why it might not be producing the expected results, given the user's specific use case. I then offered an alternative approach using Join, which was intended to serve as a starting point for discussion. If there was a misunderstanding or if my initial response was not clear enough, I apologize for any confusion.

Comment: No. You said *To achieve the desired behavior, you need to perform a cross join...*, then showed a query dat doesn't do that and yet continu saying *This will give you the desired result*. ChatGPT generates text like that without blinking, that's why gen-AI isn't tolerated here. It causes many people a lot of work scrutinizing eloquent but totally wrong answers. That said, if you improve an answer there's no need to keep showing the old part.

Comment: I understand your concerns about the accuracy and clarity of the information provided. However, I'd like to clarify that my initial response was based on the user's specific query and issue with `GroupJoin`. The term "cross join" may have been misleading; the intent was to show a `Join` operation that could potentially solve the user's problem. I acknowledge that the language could have been clearer, but the core aim was to offer a viable alternative for the issue at hand. Appreciate the scrutiny, the goal is to provide accurate & helpful info. To jump to accusations is bit antagonistic.